# USB not working on VMWare workstation 7 host

Tags: vmware-workstation

After I have installed VMWare Workstation 7 on my Win 7 all USB devices are not working / showing up on my host machine ??

Answer (score 2):

Enable your USB device in Host OS using VM (in the menubar) -> Removable devices. On your selected device click "Connect".